# Why mysql fulltext search not run as expected?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a table with 700, 000 rows. One column called 'data' is text type. I add fulltext index on this column to improve my query speed.

Here are two query, the second not return as expected.

You can see that the first query return one result with the keywords I specified.
It took 2 seconds

I thought the second query should run faster since I give more filter condition. But it tooks about one minute.

Giving more conditions should narrow down the data set to search, why it slower?

MYSQL version is 8.0.16 Engine is InnoDB. Sorry about the Mosaic

[image]

Comment: The query returns what you're asking for. Not what you want. You need literal, not fulltext, matching, so your substring to be searched must be enclosed with double quote chars. Test `+"i-uf16..."`.

Comment: Hi @Akina thanks.  I did the way you said and it run correctly, but the speed is slow.  Shold not it be faster since more condition means smaller scope to search?  I modified the question. Can you help to check again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Giving more conditions should narrow down the data set to search, why it slower?

FULLTEXT will search for each required string, getting a list of row numbers (or something equivalent).

For multiple required strings, it will get multiple lists and "AND" them together.

Furthermore, when there are two strings ("26228" and "31500733" in quotes together, their adjacency needs to be verified.  *This* *may* be the slow part.

Consider this instead

```
MATCH AGAINST(+uf8... +26228 +31500733 IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

That won't test the adjacency, but that might not matter to the end results.  (Note also that I skipped the too-short "i".)